# Is my domain mapping negatively affecitng me for SEO?

Tags: dns, seo, mapping

Consider this:

example.com is equivalent to domain.com/example

this is also true

example.com/subfolder is equivalent to example.com/example/subfolder

as a result of the domain mapping / .htaccess

is this bad?

to further elaborate, I am hosting multiple domains on the same ip

Comment: wondering if it helped?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Search engines has the concept of **duplicate content** and that is exactly what will happen in your case.

If `example.com/subfolder` and `example.com/example/subfolder` have same content and is not marked as canonical of one another, then search engines considers them as **duplicate**. Your own page competes against each other, which will hurt the SEO values. In order to solve it, pick your preferred domain and do `<linl rel=canonical href='your preferred domain' />` the other one to that.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I decided to prioritize and purchase small VPS's to put the individual domains on... you could just do a single dedicated server with a lot of ip addresses... but $2.99 for a VPS  per month is not bad for a single website. I'll have to investigate with <linl (link?) rel=canonical href='preferred domain' />

Comment: Also they are not duplicates, there is only one content, but the domain mapping eg. sharing the same ip address... it's pretending as if each website has its own ip but they are linked to each other... maybe that is what you mean by duplicate...

Comment: domain.com is the primary domain eg. domain #1, example.com is domain #2 which is a sub folder of domain #1... so if you were to say domain.com/example this is equivalent to example.com